# JSHint silence "Variable is defined but never used"

Tags: javascript, jshint

I want to silence the JSHint warning *"attrs is defined but never used"* for the variable `attrs`. However I do not want to use the option `/* jshint unused:false */` since this will turn off the warning altogether. I want the warning to be disabled only for `attrs`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

#### For global variables

Add

```
/* exported variableNameHere */
```

at the top of your script. In your case, replace `variableNameHere` with `attrs`. This tells jshint that `attrs` will be used elsewhere.

For multiple variables:

```
/* exported attrs, somethingElse, somethingElse2 */
```

[Docs here](http://www.jshint.com/docs/).

#### For local variables

You can ignore **all** unused local variables within a given function scope using the method outlined in [this jshint commit](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/commit/4ac15f640d080f9ab146e8851177019bdc0d14a6) and this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/639/). Example:

```
//jshint unused:true
var a;

function foo(b) {
    //jshint unused:false
    return 1;
}

foo();

// ->
// Line 1: 'a' is defined but never used.
```

This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere else, but works when tested on http://jshint.com/

Comment: Note::To 'import' it somewhere else you would use 
/* global attrs, somethingElse, somethinElse2 */

Comment: If your issue is with function parameters, you can use ```/* jshint unused: vars */``` as described [here](http://jslint.fantasy.codes/a-is-defined-but-never-used/).

Comment: Not working for me either, through `"grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.10.0"`